# Not able to change json value of number to double quote

Tags: python, json, string, dataframe

Input:df=

```
{      
Name: "test",
Address: "xyz",
"Age": 40,
"Info": "test"
}
```

Output:

```
{      
Name: "test",
Address: "xyz",
"Age": "40",
"Info": "test"
}
```

Note: I have tried `json.dumps(df)`
It is converting to string but numeric value i.e 40 in my example is not returning in double quote.
Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: Do you use a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: Can you show something from your shell?

Comment: @Corralien  , yes I use pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dataframe looks like:

```
print(df)

# Output
   Name Address  Age  Info
0  test     xyz   40  test
1  test     abc   20  test
```

and if you want to convert numeric values as string:

```
out = df.astype(str).to_json(orient='records', indent=4)
print(out)

# Output
[
    {
        "Name":"test",
        "Address":"xyz",
        "Age":"40",
        "Info":"test"
    },
    {
        "Name":"test",
        "Address":"abc",
        "Age":"20",
        "Info":"test"
    }
]
```